# c++ static observer class

Tags: c++, multithreading, observer-pattern, static-class

I have two programs: a server and a client

```
class client
{
 private:
  Network    net;
  Gui        gui;
};
```

Here's the Network class

```
class Network
{
  public:
   void      receivePacket(packet)
   {
     Protocol::readPacket(packet)
   }
};
```

Here's the Gui class

```
class Gui
{
 private:
  std::string   informations;

 public:
  void          displayInfo();
  void          updateInformation(information);
};
```

And here's Protocol

```
class Protocol
{
     static void     readPacket(packet)
     {
       if (packet.command == "refreshGui")
         //I need somehow to call GUI::UpdateInformation here and give the information from packet.information
     }
};
```

Protocol is considered as a "static class" which means that in shouldn't be instantiate. So the idea is that, when `Protocol::readPacket` get a `packet` from the server, it should be able to send the information to the `GUI`. However, it's not always the case, so passing a point/reference is not what I'm looking for.

It's not well illustrated but the idea is:
- `Protocol::readPacket` seek if we need to call `GUI`
- Protocol shouldn't take another argument, and shouldn't be instantiate.

Someone gave me the advice about using Observer-pattern. `Protocol` would be the subject and `GUI` the Observer. However, I couldn't make it without instantiate Protocol.

So is there a way to do it without instantiate Protocol ?

Comment: What is `Protocol`?

Comment: @i_am_jorf I updated the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In distributed computing, it is a common pattern for the network manager of a node to receive a message and call a dispatcher associated with the message type. Your need is quite similar. Here is what you could do:

- In your Network class, maintain an unordered_map< packet_type, std::function >.
- When your program starts, push into that unordered_map an std::pair<"refreshGui", Gui::UpdateInformation>
- In Network::receivePacket, retrieve the function from the unordered_map and call it.

Comment: it would work if I didn't need to give the information from packet.information to the GUI

Comment: In my solution, there is nothing preventing you from calling Gui::UpdateInformation with arguments.

Comment: But Gui::UpdateInformation is supposed to be called in Protocol::readPacket actually.

Comment: Think of the idea I gave you as a high-level guideline how things should be done. Adjust it based on your context. If you need to call Gui::UpdateInformation in Protocol::readPacket, you may keep the unordered_map as a static variable inside a static member function of Protocol. In Procolol::readPacket, call that static member function to get the unordered_map.